# How does work a polling interval for session statistics?

Tags: analytics

I am using a software (HPE ALM, but it is not important here) that displays its license usage daily peaks. A license token is used for each session and released at the end of the session. And all sessions are stored into a session history table (on MS SQL Server).

When I run this kind of queries:

```
SELECT TOP 1 count(*) as CountSimultaneous
FROM td.SESSIONS_HISTORY T1, td.SESSIONS_HISTORY T2
WHERE td.SESSIONS_HISTORY.CLIENT_TYPE = 'Application Lifecycle Management Client UI'
and T1.START_TIME between T2.START_TIME and T2.END_TIME
/* Add here the start/end dates */
GROUP BY T1.SESSION_ID
ORDER BY CountSimultaneous DESC;
```

The numbers slightly differ from what I get with Licence Usage tab (my peak is 10 up to 20 higher).

According to a well informed user, the difference is due to the fact that there is some polling interval involved.

How does work a polling interval approach? Are some samples taken randomly from the session history table. For example top 10 of sessions between (START_TIME - x - 5 minutes) and (END_TIME - x); when x varies in the considered period of time (yesterday, last week, last month, etc.).

I'm not interrested in getting the same results than the vendor. The objective is to understand this concept that seems to be used in other tools (Analytics, LoadRunner, etc.).

An answer with an example of pseudo code / SQL will be much appreciated (even if it is taken from another tool).

Comment: I won't be providing SQL for you, but I will point out that the only way to get the same peak as the vendor is to match your sample rate to theirs.

Comment: I'm not insterrested in getting the same peak as the vendor. I'd like to understand how does the approach work, as I have only a basic knowledge in analytics. I will edit the question for clarity, but I'm not asking to code something for me, just a practical example.

Answer (score 0):

It's too much work to draw a picture, but let's assume you have `(time, session count)` data that look like this:

```
(0, 10)
(1, 10)
(2, 10)
(3, 50)
(4, 10)
(5, 10)
```

If your vendor measures every second, they'll see the spike of 50 at time = 3.

If you sample or query every five seconds you'll see a peak value of 10.  You'll miss the spike at 50.

Comment: It is not exactly clear for me because the input data is not (time, session count), but (session start datetime, session end datetime). It is not coming from a time series database or a measure taken into a dataflow such as a system metric.

Comment: I could make it time series data.  If I query for DISTINCT START, COUNT(*) I get counts down to the millisecond.  You start aggregating by counting between date ranges.